# add event listener more than once

Tags: javascript, events, event-listener

on my input i draw text on a canvas on every type. my problem is , if i want to change the location on which the text will be display , i call the onTyping function again with a different height value, but thr eventlisetner is keep on listening to the type on both location, and i cant figare when to stop it. (i type on the input and see on the canvas ob both locations (line height) at once.)

hope my problem is clear , thank you !

```
<input onkeyup="onTyping()" class="text" onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value=""/> 

<button class="lines" onclick="SwitchLine()"><img src="icons/up-and-down-opposite-double-arrows-side-by-side.png" alt=""></button>

let gLineLocation = 0 ;

function onTyping(canvasHeight = 50) {
  let inputText = "";
  let text = document.querySelector(".text");
  text.addEventListener("input", (ev) => {
    inputText = ev.target.value;
    gCtx.font = "40px Impact";
    // ctx.fillStyle = "red";/
    gCtx.strokeText(inputText, 20, canvasHeight);
});

}
function SwitchLine() {
gLineLocation++;

if (gLineLocation === 1) {
    onTyping (gCanvas.height / 2)
}
if (gLineLocation === 2) {
    onTyping(gCanvas.height - 10)
    gLineLocation=0;
}
}
```

Comment: `.addEventListener()` does not remove previously-added event listener functions. All of them will be called.

Comment: If you are happy with having `gLineLocation` reside in the outer scope here, then you could put `canvasHeight` in that same scope, instead of passing it into `onTyping` as a parameter. Then you could use _one_ event handler function, without any need to manipulate _that_.

Comment: Pointy – to clarify for the reader of this thread – "all of them will be called *once."*

Comment: thank you . i declare this var as global for now.